# How to send post restful api with header, params, and body as a rest template in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I need to consume restful api that required header, body, and params.

Are there any way to send params, body, and headers together with resttemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you can do it -> https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-resttemplate-post-request-json-headers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Webclient to post message to specific e/p,
ref - https://medium.com/p/9863094bac3
for ex-

```
UriCimponenets uriComponents =UriComponentsBuilds.fromHttpUrl(“http://endpoint/{param}")
 .buildAndExpand(inputParam);
HttpHeaders headers= new HttpHeaders ();
Webclient webclient;
//post response status of operation .
String response=webclient.method(HttpMethod.POST)
      .uri (uriComponents.toUri())
      .headers(httpHeaders-> {
               httpHeaders.add(“key”,”value”);
                })
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(<jsonStringBody>))
      .exchange()
      .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
           if(clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError())
              {
             clientResponse->             {clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class).subscriber(errorBody->log.error(error.Body));
    return Mono.Error(new                  ResponseStatusException(clientResponse.statusCode()));
             }
           else 
             return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);                           })
      .doOnSuccess(clientResposne -> { log.info(“Response:       {}”,clientResponse)})
      .block(Duration,ofSeconds(50));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of send Post request using RestTemplate:

```
// pretend RestTemplate already initialized

String url = "your url";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION.JSON); // whatever u want
headers.set("KEY", "VALUE");

HttpEntity requestHeader = new HttpEntity(headers);

// set url, header, and Type of value to be returned from the request
ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, requestHeader, String.class);
```